# Discord.js DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

first of all, I've tried several solutions to the same problems, but I can't get any results. The bot is for registering users on discord for an MMORPG game that uses an api to check if the character's name belongs to the alliance clans and if so:

The command the bot uses `/register name level`.
What it does when using the command for a user not registered in the database:

**1. Checks if the character's name belongs to any alliance clan in the database and if so, it also checks if there is already a character registered, if not, registers it in the database as `id, user_id, name, class_name, clan_name, server_name and date`.;**

**2. Grants specific roles;**

**3. Change nickname to character name;**

**4. Send embed with character information;**

```js
Successfully registered Character "DLC DARKLORD"!
E:\AREA DE TRABALHO BKP\BOTS UTEIS e FUNCIONAIS\NEW MOOMOO JULIEX V3\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:687
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
            ^

DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at handleErrors (E:\AREA DE TRABALHO BKP\BOTS UTEIS e FUNCIONAIS\NEW MOOMOO JULIEX V3\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:687:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (E:\AREA DE TRABALHO BKP\BOTS UTEIS e FUNCIONAIS\NEW MOOMOO JULIEX V3\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:786:23)
    at async _REST.request (E:\AREA DE TRABALHO BKP\BOTS UTEIS e FUNCIONAIS\NEW MOOMOO JULIEX V3\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1218:22)
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.reply (E:\AREA DE TRABALHO BKP\BOTS UTEIS e FUNCIONAIS\NEW MOOMOO JULIEX V3\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:111:5) { 
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: undefined,
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: [
          {
            color: 1752220,
            title: 'Successfully Registered!',
            fields: [Array],
            thumbnail: [Object],
            image: [Object]
          }
        ],
        components: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: undefined,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined,
        thread_name: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
```

Register.js

````js
const { ApplicationCommandOptionType, EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const axios = require('axios');

function getCharacterData(name) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const api_url = "https://api.mir4info.com/v5/search/";
        const result = await axios.get(api_url + name);
        const text = await result.data;
        if (Array.isArray(text)) {
            if (text.length===1) {
                const character = text[0]
                resolve(character);
            } else if (text.length>1) {
                for (const character of text) {
                    character.clan_name = character.clan_name.replace(/[\u0080-\uffff]/g, (char) => '\\u' + ('0000' + char.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4));
                    if (character.match_type == "exact") {
                        resolve(character);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (text.error) {
            reject(text.error);
        } else {
            reject(text);
        }
    });
};

module.exports = {
    name: "register",
    name_localizations: {
        "en-US": "register",
        "pt-BR": "registrar",
        "es-ES": "registrarse",
        "zh-CN": "注册",
        "ko": "등록"
    },
    description: "Registers your MIR4 Character",
    description_localizations: {
        "en-US": "Registers your MIR4 Character",
        "pt-BR": "Registrar seu personagem no MIR4",
        "es-ES": "Registrarse tu personaje de MIR4",
        "zh-CN": "注册您的 MIR4 角色",
        "ko": "MIR4 캐릭터 등록"
    },
    options: [
        {
            name: "name",
            name_localizations: {
                "en-US": "name",
                "pt-BR": "nome",
                "es-ES": "nombre",
                "zh-CN": "名称",
                "ko": "이름"
            },
            description: "Your exact MIR4 Character Name",
            description_localizations: {
                "en-US": "Your exact MIR4 Character Name",
                "pt-BR": "Nome exato do seu personagem no MIR4",
                "es-ES": "Tu nombre exacto de personaje de MIR4",
                "zh-CN": "您精确的MIR4角色名称",
                "ko": "정확한 MIR4 캐릭터 이름"
            },
            type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: "level",
            name_localizations: {
                "en-US": "level",
                "pt-BR": "nível",
                "es-ES": "nivel",
                "zh-CN": "水平",
                "ko": "수평"
            },
            description: "Your MIR4 Character Level",
            description_localizations: {
                "en-US": "Your MIR4 Character Level",
                "pt-BR": "Seu nível de personagem MIR4",
                "es-ES": "Tu nivel de personaje de MIR4",
                "zh-CN": "您的MIR4角色级别",
                "ko": "MIR4 캐릭터 레벨"
            },
            type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Integer,
            required: true,
            min_value: 95,
            max_value: 140,
        },
    ],

    run: async(client, interaction) => {
        const option = interaction.options;
        const member = interaction.member;
        const user = member.user;
        const name = option.getString("name");
        const level = option.getInteger("level");
        const roles = {
            tower1: "1156764474284449802",
            tower2: "1156764518991548486",
            tower3: "1156764561152679966"
        };
        getCharacterData(name)
            .then(char => {
                    // Verificar se o membro é o proprietário do servidor
                    if (member.id === interaction.guild.ownerId) {
                        return interaction.reply({
                            content: "Desculpe, não consigo alterar o apelido do proprietário do servidor.",
                            ephemeral: true
                        });
                    }
                            client.database.addCharacter(user, char)
                    .then(async (msg) => {
                        console.log(msg);
                        if (level >= 95 && level <= 120) {
                            await member.roles.add(roles.tower1);
                        }
                        if (level >= 115 && level <= 130) {
                            await member.roles.add(roles.tower2);
                        }
                        if (level <= 140) {
                            await member.roles.add(roles.tower3);
                        }
                            
                        await member.setNickname(char.name); // Adicionando o nickname
                        const class_role = await interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == `${char.class_name}`);
                        const clan_role = await interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == `${char.clan_name}`);
                        const server_role = await interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == `${char.server_name}`);
                        if (!class_role) {
                            interaction.guild.roles.create({
                                name: char.class_name,
                                reason: `Create missing Role: ${char.class_name}`
                            })
                                .then(async (role) => {
                                    await member.roles.add(role.id);
                                })
                                .catch(console.error);
                        } else {
                            await member.roles.add(class_role.id);
                        }
                        if (!clan_role) {
                            interaction.guild.roles.create({
                                name: char.clan_name,
                                reason: `Create missing Role: ${char.clan_name}`
                            })
                                .then(async (role) => {
                                    await member.roles.add(role.id);
                                })
                                .catch(console.error);
                        } else {
                            await member.roles.add(clan_role.id);
                        }
                        if (!server_role) {
                            interaction.guild.roles.create({
                                name: char.server_name,
                                reason: `Create missing Role: ${char.server_name}`
                            })
                                .then(async (role) => {
                                    await member.roles.add(role.id);
                                })
                                .catch(console.error);
                        } else {
                            await member.roles.add(server_role.id);
                        }
                            
                        await interaction.reply({
                            embeds: [
                                new EmbedBuilder()
                                    .setColor("Aqua")
                                    .setTitle("Successfully Registered!")
                                    .addFields(
                                        {
                                            name: "Name",
                                            value: "```" + char.name + "```",
                                            inline: true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            name: "Class",
                                            value: "```" + char.class_name + "```",
                                            inline: true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            name: "Power",
                                            value: "```" + char.power + "```",
                                            inline: false
                                        },
                                        {
                                            name: "Region",
                                            value: "```" + char.region_name + "```",
                                            inline: true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            name: "Server",
                                            value: "```" + char.region_name + "```",
                                            inline: true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            name: "Clan",
                                            value: "```" + char.clan_name + "```",
                                            inline: false
                                        }
                                    )
                                    .setThumbnail(client.class_icons[char.class_name])
                                    .setImage(client.class_banners[char.class_name])
                            ]
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(async (err) => {
                        console.error(err);
                        if (String(err).includes("Error 409")) {
                            await interaction.reply({
                                embeds: [
                                    new EmbedBuilder()
                                        .setColor("Red")
                                        .setTitle("Error 409: Duplicate Character")
                                        .setDescription("A Character with that Name is already registered!")
                                        .setTimestamp()
                                ],
                                ephemeral: true
                            });
                        } else if (String(err).includes("Error 400")) {
                            if (String(err).includes("Clan")) {
                                await interaction.reply({
                                    embeds: [
                                        new EmbedBuilder()
                                            .setColor("Red")
                                            .setTitle(`${err}`)
                                            .setDescription("You may not register a Character that is not a member of a Clan in the Alliance!")
                                            .setTimestamp()
                                    ],
                                    ephemeral: true
                                });
                            } else {
                                await interaction.reply({
                                    embeds: [
                                        new EmbedBuilder()
                                            .setColor("Red")
                                            .setTitle(`${err}`)
                                            .setDescription("You may not register more than one Character!")
                                            .setTimestamp()
                                    ],
                                    ephemeral: true
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            await interaction.reply({
                                embeds: [
                                    new EmbedBuilder()
                                        .setColor("Red")
                                        .setTitle("An Error occurred...")
                                        .setDescription(`${err}`)
                                        .setTimestamp()
                                ],
                                ephemeral: true
                            });
                        }
                    });
            })
            .catch(async (err) => {
                await interaction.reply({
                    embeds: [
                        new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setColor("Red")
                            .setDescription(`${err}`)
                            .setTimestamp()
                    ],
                    ephemeral: true
                });
            });
    },
};
````

psql.js (functions `getCharacter and addCharacter`)

```js
    getCharacter(player, char) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.getPlayer(player)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('char.id:', char.id); // Adiciona este console.log
                    if (!char) {
                        const sql = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE id = $1";
                        this.query(sql, [char.id])
                            .then(results => {
                                if (results.length===0) {
                                    reject("Error 404: No Characters found");
                                } else {
                                    resolve(results);
                                }
                            })
                            .catch(err => reject(err));
                    } else {
                        const sql = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE name = $1";
                        this.query(sql, [char.name])
                            .then() //Executes if a character with the ID is found (or not found)
                            .catch() //Executes if there was an error with the Query
                        const sql1 = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE id = $1 AND name = $2";
                        this.query(sql1, [char.id, char.name])
                            .then(results => {
                                if (results.length===0) {
                                    const sql2 = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE user_id = $1";
                                    this.query(sql2, [player.id])
                                        .then(result => {
                                            if (result.length===0) {
                                                reject("Error 404: No Characters found");
                                            } else if (result.length===1) {
                                                reject("Error 400: Forbidden");
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .catch(err => reject(err));
                                } else if (results.length===1) {
                                    resolve(results[0]);
                                }
                            })
                            .catch(err => reject(err));
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => reject(err));
        });
    };

    addCharacter(player, char) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.getClan({name: char.clan_name})
                .then((clan) => {
                    this.getCharacter(player, char)
                        .then(() => reject("Error 409: Duplicate Character"))
                        .catch(err => {
                            if (String(err).includes("Error 404")) {
                                const date = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                                const sql = "INSERT INTO characters VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8)";
                                this.query(sql, [char.id, player.id, char.name, char.class_name, char.power, char.server_name, clan.id, date])
                                    .then(resolve(`Successfully registered Character \"${char.name}\"!`))
                                    .catch(err1 => reject(err1));
                            } else {
                                reject(err);
                            }
                        });
                })
                .catch(() => reject("Error 400: Forbidden Clan"));
        });
    };
```